# Extract a value out of mongoose find() query

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Upon on the mongoose query of find ("-_id services.location"), the output on stringifying is:

```
[
   {
      "services":[
         {
            "location":[
               17.4374614,
               78.7482878
            ]
         },
         {
            "location":[
               17.4020637,
               78.18400519324596
            ]
         },
         {
            "location":[
               17.56208737,
               78.284005186526
            ]
         },
         {
            "location":[
               17.5620637,
               78.3240051999554
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Is there any way where i can  get to access each individual value of location like( 17.4374614, 78.7482878,17.4020637....) from the output I got.

My schema is as follows:-

```
var serviceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    location:[{type: Number}]
})
```

Comment: Check my answer below also try the link I shared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated the answer for:**

> Is there any way to render only the array of loc values without _id
>   into the templates. I only need to render the values of array of loc

Here's how you can do it: https://mongoplayground.net/p/VhrZKxg6OC1

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$services"
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$services.location"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "location": "$services.location"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "_id",
      loc: {
        $push: "$location"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "_id": 0,
      "locationArray": "$loc"
    }
  }
])
```

This will result:

```
[
  {
    "locationArray": [
      17.4374614,
      78.7482878,
      17.4020637,
      78.18400519324597,
      17.56208737,
      78.284005186526,
      17.5620637,
      78.3240051999554
    ]
  }
]
```

Hope it solves your query.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. Is there any way to render only the array of loc values without _id into the templates. I only need to render the values of array of loc.

Comment: Just add one more project statement with with _id:0 and loc:”$loc”

Comment: I have changed the project statement to:- $project:
      {
      "_id": "0",
      "location": "$services.location",
      "loc":"$loc"
    }    Yet the outcome of the query is not of the form loc:[ 17.4374614,
      78.7482878,
      17.4020637,
      78.18400519324597,
      17.56208737,
      78.284005186526,
      17.5620637,
      78.3240051999554 ]  i want to send only the flat array values of loc to the template

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks a ton! :)

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the [`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) and [`$concatArrays`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays) operators.

```
[
  {
    "$project": {
      "result": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$services.location",
          "initialValue": [],
          "in": {
            "$concatArrays": [
              "$$this",
              "$$value"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

[See demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/d4tTPDcNINM)

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. Is there any way to render only the array of result values without _id into the templates. I only need to render the values of array of result

Comment: Great answer @styvane!! +1 for you!! @Drunken Lord check this link I have updated his query to match your requirement: https://mongoplayground.net/p/EKm7PBH7NTy